# How to check whether the assigned work for button click( click method or command) is completed or not. without accessing the code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf

Consider I am having a button called "Add" and is bind with the command "AddBtnExceuteCommand".

Consider Execute() method of this Command having very large and time consuming calculations.

I am developing a tool which will save the Actions like Click, Entering text into textbox etc. When I play it back the same actions will executed automatically.

consider I started recording actions. Lets say I have Clicked on Button called "Add". this click actions will save in some file called "Actions.xml". When I Started playing back that saved action by reading "Actions.xml" file. I have only Control over the Button not on the code behind of that button(means I do not have access to the AddBtnExceuteCommand command).
My Actions.Xml have lot of such actions which will be executed serially.

What I want===>

When I started Reading Actions.xml that will execute saved Actions(Clicks) automatically without considering whether the Code behind of button is executed or not. I want to Restrict the execution of second action unless The code behind of first Button is executed. So to do that I need to know whether the Code behind for that button click is  executed or not. I am not having access to the code behind. I have  controls(this is not wpf Controls) on Button. 
I have Used White TestStack framework to get the control of Windows controls(like Button)

My UI may be Responsive while button click method performing lengthy calculations. UI might be on different thread.

So is it possible to check whether the code behind for that button click is executed or not. I wanted to check it only from button control.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure, if it is possible to do, if your command is executing job on other than UI thread.
You could try to monitor `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads` and after your event handler is executed

Comment: Also .net profiling api might be helpful.

Comment: What you mean by code behind? Is this a Web App? WPF? Windows forms? There are several ways of doing so, but I can't see your whole scenario yet.

Comment: @rodrigogq Its WPF App. Code behind means the code which will be executed on clicks. for e.g: If I clicked on Button called "Add" the code for addition is Code behind. when we used MVVM the term code behind is generally used. If you want any more clarification about question please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are telling you having two logics:

1. Logic for the click
2. Logic for "enabling" the button

I guess you need to use a `RelayCommand` from the `GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command` (please check [this URL](http://www.mvvmlight.net/installing/) on how to install and [this one](http://www.mvvmlight.net/doc/) on how use it).
Basically, you just bind your command in the view:

```
<Button Command="{Binding StoreActionCommand}"/>
```

And in the ViewModel ("code behind"), you specify two different actions: one is what the button do, and the next one is if this code can be executed.
You need to add this to the constructor of your ViewModel:

```
// declare your public attribute (it can be a property too if you want)
public ICommand StoreActionCommand;

// and on your ViewModel constructor
StoreActionCommand = new RelayCommand(StoreCommandExecute, CanStoreCommand);

private void StoreCommandExecute()
{
    // here you add actions to your queue
}

private bool CanStoreCommand()
{
    // here, you can check if your queue is empty or not..
    return true;
}
```

If you want to add items, do you need to store it on an XML? Could it be just memory based? You could use a `Queue` for it.

For the background Thread, I would advise you to start working with the Task library. Besides being easier to understand, it is easier to control it. And never from your background thread try to interact with the UI. you can do it with some thread synchronization, but I would not recommend it. If you are doing something in the background, let it only do something and then return. Otherwise, use the `IProgress` classes to notify changes in the UI.

---

**EDIT**

I still note sure if that's what your looking for, but I'll try to help you again.

I usually do that do notify the UI when I have to do a background task notifying changes to the UI. You can use the `IProgress` to change some ***properties*** that are used by your UI. Note that you do not change the UI directly.. never! You just need to make a set of properties that do that for you.

First, create some properties so that your UI can connect to them:

```
private string executionStatus = string.Empty;
public string ExecutionStatus
{
    get { return executionStatus; }
    set
    {
        executionStatus = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(ExecutionStatus));
    }
}

private bool canRun = true;
public bool CanRun
{
    get { return canRun; }
    set
    {
        canRun = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(CanRun));
    }
}
```

Then, change the `StoreActionCommand` and `CanStoreCommand` to something like:

```
private bool CanStoreCommand()
{
    return CanRun;
}

// note the async here
private async void StoreActionCommand()
{
    CanRun = false;

    // notification
    var progressNotification = new Progress<string>((value) => ExecutionStatus = value);
    // real background thread goes here, without blocking the UI
    await Task.Run(() => {
        DoWork(progressNotification);
    });

    CanRun = True;
}

private void DoWork(IProgress<string> progress)
{
    progress.Report("Starting...");
    try
    {
        progress.Report("doing x...");
        progress.Report("doing y...");
    }
    catch(Exception err)
    {
        progress.Report(err);
    }
    progress.Report("Process finished");
}
```

Hope this helps you.
If you have to work on more items, you could control the CanRun as you want.
Another interesting stuff is that you could create a Model class in order to send more than just a string (you can pass a status and a flag indicating the possibility of the user to click the CanRun button during the work, but then a new Thread would be fired in parallel do the one that is already running).

Comment: I have used all MVVM, bind all button with command successfully that is not issue. Issue is what I want to check whether the code behind(in your code above StoreCommandExecute() ) is successfully executed or not from UI only. not from StoreCommandExecute()  method.

Comment: @YogeshWavhal I modified my comments with more info, please check if that is what you are looking for